# ROS2 Subscription Callback not called with GAZEBO

Tags: ros, gazebo, ros2, callback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am having a problem on my first ROS2 node.
I setup the turtlebot3 packages using this [link](http://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/ros2_setup/) (only Remote PC since I don't have a robot). Started the GAZEBO simulation using these [instructions](http://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/ros2_simulation/#simulation). After I run `ros2 launch turtlebot3_gazebo empty_world.launch.py` I can do `ros2 topic echo /scan` and receive data.

After this I created a colcon pkg using this [tutorial](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Tutorials/Writing-A-Simple-Py-Publisher-And-Subscriber/#id6) and wrote following code:

```
import rclpy   
from rclpy.node import Node   
from sensor_msgs.msg import LaserScan   

class Platooning(Node):
    def __init__(self):
        # ROS Stuff #
        super().__init__("platooning")
        self.get_logger().info("Started init Node")
        self.sub_lidar = self.create_subscription(LaserScan, "/scan", self.lidar_callback, 10)
        self.get_logger().info("Finished init node {}".format(self.get_name()))
    def lidar_callback(self, msg):
        print("Callback")
        self.get_logger().info("I heard: {}".format(msg))

def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)
    control = Platooning()
    try:
        while(1):
            rclpy.spin(control)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Exception: {}".format(e))
    control.destroy_node()
    rclpy.shutdown()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I build the package using `colcon build --symlink-install --packages-select platooning` and start it using `ros2 run platooning main`.

The `lidar_callback` functions does not print anything using just gazebo, but as soon as I do `ros2 topic pub /scan sensor_msgs/msg/LaserScan  -1` the `lidar_callback` is executed.

Can somebody please help me?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/344939/ros2-subscription-callback-not-called-with-gazebo/) by [GeorgNo](https://answers.ros.org/users/44912/georgno/) on ROS Answers with karma: 183 on 2020-02-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem was that the subscriber had a wrong [quality of service profile](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Concepts/About-Quality-of-Service-Settings/).

Here the fix:

```
from rclpy.qos import qos_profile_sensor_data
.
.
.
self.sub_lidar = self.create_subscription(LaserScan, "/scan", self.lidar_callback, qos_profile=qos_profile_sensor_data)
```

---

Originally posted by [GeorgNo](https://answers.ros.org/users/44912/georgno/) with karma: 183 on 2020-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1